# Getting partial json response for s3select with aws java sdk v2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk, amazon-s3-select

I am trying to implement s3select in a spring boot app to query parquet file in s3 bucket, I am only getting partial result from the s3select output, Please help to identify the issue, i have used aws java sdk v2.

Upon checking the json output(printed in the console), overall characters in the output is 65k.

I am using eclipse and tried unchecking "Limit console output" in the console preference, which did not help.

Code is here:-

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.async.SdkPublisher;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3AsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CompressionType;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.EndEvent;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ExpressionType;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.InputSerialization;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.JSONOutput;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.OutputSerialization;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ParquetInput;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.RecordsEvent;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.SelectObjectContentEventStream;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.SelectObjectContentEventStream.EventType;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.SelectObjectContentRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.SelectObjectContentResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.SelectObjectContentResponseHandler;

public class ParquetSelect {
    
    private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "<bucket-name>";
    private static final String KEY = "<object-key>";
    private static final String QUERY = "select * from S3Object s";
    public static S3AsyncClient s3;
    

    public static void selectObjectContent() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        
        SelectQueryWithHandler(handler).join();

        RecordsEvent recordsEvent = (RecordsEvent) handler.receivedEvents.stream()
                                                                         .filter(e -> e.sdkEventType() == EventType.RECORDS)
                                                                         .findFirst()
                                                                         .orElse(null);

        System.out.println(recordsEvent.payload().asUtf8String());

    }

    private static CompletableFuture<Void> SelectQueryWithHandler(SelectObjectContentResponseHandler handler) {
        InputSerialization inputSerialization = InputSerialization.builder()
                                                                  .parquet(ParquetInput.builder().build())
                                                                  .compressionType(CompressionType.NONE)
                                                                  .build();


        OutputSerialization outputSerialization = OutputSerialization.builder()
                                                                     .json(JSONOutput.builder().build())
                                                                     .build();


        SelectObjectContentRequest select = SelectObjectContentRequest.builder()
                                                                      .bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
                                                                      .key(KEY)
                                                                      .expression(QUERY)
                                                                      .expressionType(ExpressionType.SQL)
                                                                      .inputSerialization(inputSerialization)
                                                                      .outputSerialization(outputSerialization)
                                                                      .build();

        return s3.selectObjectContent(select, handler);
    }

    private static class Handler implements SelectObjectContentResponseHandler {
        private SelectObjectContentResponse response;
        private List<SelectObjectContentEventStream> receivedEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        private Throwable exception;

        @Override
        public void responseReceived(SelectObjectContentResponse response) {
            this.response = response;
        }

        @Override
        public void onEventStream(SdkPublisher<SelectObjectContentEventStream> publisher) {
            publisher.subscribe(receivedEvents::add);
        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionOccurred(Throwable throwable) {
            exception = throwable;
        }

        @Override
        public void complete() {
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you may get multiple RecordsEvent events, each containing an InputStream with a part of the data - so you have to iterate through events and join them:

```kotlin
fun selectS3ObjectContent(socRequest: SelectObjectContentRequest): InputStream {
    val handler = S3SelectObjectContentHandler()
    asyncS3.selectObjectContent(socRequest, handler).join()

    return if (handler.receivedEvents.filterIsInstance<RecordsEvent>().isEmpty())
        InputStream.nullInputStream()
    else
        handler.receivedEvents.filterIsInstance<RecordsEvent>().map {
            it.payload().asInputStream()
        }.reduce { l, r ->
            SequenceInputStream(l, r)
        }
}

class S3SelectObjectContentHandler : SelectObjectContentResponseHandler {
    private var response: SelectObjectContentResponse? = null
    var receivedEvents = ArrayList<SelectObjectContentEventStream>()
    private var exception: Throwable? = null

    override fun responseReceived(response: SelectObjectContentResponse?) {
        this.response = response
    }

    override fun onEventStream(publisher: SdkPublisher<SelectObjectContentEventStream>) {
        publisher.subscribe { event ->
            receivedEvents.add(event)
        }
    }

    override fun exceptionOccurred(throwable: Throwable?) {
        exception = throwable
    }

    override fun complete() { /* no-op */ }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked, although I have one question, Will order of the RecordEvents(with which we would get InputStream) always be same as the actual Results, and we are not at the risk of making sequenceinputstream with inputstreams in irregular order? because I even noticed the inputstream is cutting off even in the middle of the json row.

Comment: My experience is that it is (so far) in correct order - we are selecting to csv output this way and didn't run into problems yet (results are in correct order, columns are matching, etc.). It makes sense it should be in correct order as it seems to be reading chunks of the output and after each chuck it creates new event.

Comment: Thank You, My input is parquet, and output is json, so far I have not seen that issue myself, but I just wanted to make sure, Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using **selectObjectContent()**. Have you tried calling the **s3AsyncClient.getObject()** method. Does that work for you?

For example, here is a code example that gets a PDF file from an Amazon S3 bucket and write the PDF file to a local file.

```
package com.example.s3.async;
// snippet-start:[s3.java2.async_stream_ops.complete]

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.async_stream_ops.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.async.AsyncResponseTransformer;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3AsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectResponse;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.async_stream_ops.import]

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.async_stream_ops.main]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class S3AsyncStreamOps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    <bucketName> <objectKey> <path>\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    bucketName - The name of the Amazon S3 bucket (for example, bucket1). \n\n" +
                "    objectKey - The name of the object (for example, book.pdf). \n" +
                "    path - The local path to the file (for example, C:/AWS/book.pdf). \n" ;

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
         }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        String objectKey = args[1];
        String path = args[2];
        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();

        GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(objectKey)
                .build();

        CompletableFuture<GetObjectResponse> futureGet = s3AsyncClient.getObject(objectRequest,
                AsyncResponseTransformer.toFile(Paths.get(path)));

        futureGet.whenComplete((resp, err) -> {
            try {
                if (resp != null) {
                    System.out.println("Object downloaded. Details: "+resp);
                } else {
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
            } finally {
               // Only close the client when you are completely done with it.
                s3AsyncClient.close();
            }
        });
        futureGet.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, This seems like good solution to get the file as it is, but I looking for options to query the parquet file and get response in json format.

Comment: Have you looked at using AWS Athena?